# I am trying to declare explicit wait in my constructor, but getting error incompatible types. How to solve it. Question related to selenium wait

Tags: selenium, wait, explicit

```
package PageObject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Amazon {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriver wait;

    public Amazon(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type = 'text']")
    WebElement search;
```

This is my code and i am getting error in the line wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
And the error is *Incompatible Type, Required : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver, Found : org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait*
Have tried this in previous code but never came across an error like this. Have imported the necessary libraries also, but not able to solve. If anyone can help to solve the error. I don't want to use Fluent wait or thread.sleep. I want the error to solve with explicit wait itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
WebDriver wait;
```

should be

```
WebDriverWait wait;
```

`WebDriverWait` is a class, and you are creating object of that class like this, so you should declare the same class.

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
```

**Full code should be :**

```
package PageObject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Amazon {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    public Amazon(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type = 'text']")
    WebElement search;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change like below. `wait` should be declared as `WebDriverWait` not `WebDriver`

```
WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;

    public Amazon(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    }
```